# ASP.NET MVC Sending Json Object with 500 internal status code

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc

Let's firstly look at the code blocks;

Controller function to send json data

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult LoadCourseForDataTable()
{
    using (var dd = new DBContext())
    {
        var data = dd.Courses.ToList();
        return Json(new {data = data}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }             
}
```

This block to get json data form the above code block;

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#CourseTable').DataTable({
            "ajax": {
                "url": "/Course/LoadCourseForDataTable",
                "type": "GET",
                "datatype": "json",
            },
            "columns": [
                { "data": "CourseID", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "Title", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "Credits", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "DepartmentID", "autoWidth": true },
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

All the libs which have to be loaded on the client server totally completed and loaded properly. They are not problem in this issue.

The server respond is **500 internal error**

Here is the detailed exception;

*The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.*

I think everything is true but I have this problem that's interesting. Can you help me? Thank you . . .

Comment: `500 Internal Server Error)` means code on the server is throwing an exception. Use your browser tools - the Network Tab - to inspect the response which will give you the details of the error.

Comment: The server will also give quite a detailed error message. What is the error?

Comment: Edited the question. Please review it.

Comment: Remove the `using` statement, or move the `return Json()` to after it.

Comment: Try using projection with `Select` method to return only the required fields. Also make sure the properties of `Course` are virtual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely because you have Lazy Loading enabled. When you are disposing the DBContext you are closing the connection to the database so it can't load any related entities after you close the using statement.

The thing is that the dispose in that using statement is run before the result from the method is passed on. And when the JsonResult try to serialize your courses they will see that there is a Lazy Loaded property and try to load it. But at this point the connection to the database is closed.

I'm strictly against Lazy Loading in web scenarios. For this reason and many others. So the only advice I will give you is disable lazy loading and if you want to include related entities you should fetch those eagerly.

Comment: I think this question is duplicated but your answer was clear and I thank you.